# How to read a MySQL database in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am a beginner in Perl. I now have an SQL statement that is working correctly, but I want to use Perl to execute the SQL and output the result to a file. Could any expert provide a very basic template (starting from connecting to the database)?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI is where the documentation is at.

Answer (score 11):

```
use DBI;
my $DBH=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:db:host","login","pass");
my $sth=$DBH->prepare("query");
$sth->execute();
while (my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array)
{
  print $row[0]."\n";
}
$sth->finish;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good tutorial (one of many):

- http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/perlmysql.htm

It has this example:

```
use DBI;
 $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:perltest','root','password')
   or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 $sql = "select * from samples";
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute
   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   print "@row\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard Perl library for database interaction is [DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) which has plenty of examples in the synopsis along with a [step through guide](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Outline-Usage) that is what you are asking for.

The usual choice for ORM is [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) which has [an introduction](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro).

Comment: From where did you get `ORM` as a likely requirement?